# Failing To Upload Items To Database Using Congomongo

Tags: mongodb, clojure

I'm using the [congomongo](https://github.com/somnium/congomongo) library in two processes. One of the processes interfaces with the databases without error. The other process is having more trouble. If I try to interact with the database from that processes slime repl, it too is has no problem, but if I try to interact through telnet things work badly.

Command Line:

```
joshua@joshua-Aspire-5251:/data/db$ telnet localhost 4576
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2286907
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Server's Reaction

```
http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2286907
Processing link.
Validating link.
Scraping item.
Wikifying items.
Uploading items.
```

From the REPL:

```
(process-link "http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2286907")
```

Server's Reaction:

```
http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2286907
Processing link.
Validating link.
Scraping item.
Wikifying items.
Uploading items.
```

The only functional difference? One actually puts the items in the database and the other doesn't. Both seem to be accomplishing everything else.

```
(ns hnparser.main
  (:use somnium.congomongo
    [hnparser.core :only [scrape-item]]))

(mongo! :db "hacker-archives")

(defn valid-link?
  [link]
  (do
    (println "Validating link.")
    (not= nil (re-matches #"http://news\.ycombinator\.com/item\?id=\d+" link))))

(defn wikify [item]
  (dissoc (assoc item :wiki [{:title (:title item)
                  :author (:user item)
                  :body (:body item)
                  :date (:date item)
                  :reason "Original post."}])
      :title :user :body :date))

(defn wikify-items [items]
  (do
    (println "Wikifying items.")
    (map wikify items)))

(defn upload-item
  [item]
  (if (nil? (fetch-one :items :where {:id (:id item)}))
    (insert! :items (assoc item :scrape-date (java.util.Date.)))))

(defn upload-items
  [items]
  (do
    (println "Uploading items.")
    (map upload-item items)))

(defn process-link
  [link]
  (do
    (println "Processing link.")
    (if (valid-link? link)
      (upload-items (wikify-items (scrape-item link))))))


(ns hnparser.server
  (:use clojure.contrib.server-socket
    hnparser.main)
  (:import [java.io PushbackReader InputStreamReader]))

(defn read-links
  [is os]
  (let [in-reader (PushbackReader. (InputStreamReader. is))]
    (let [input (str (read in-reader))]
      (do
    (println input)
    (process-link input)))))

(defn -main
  []
  (def *server* (create-server 4576 read-links)))
```

Note that this successfully scrapes (verified through print statements). It just doesn't upload to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map is lazy: you should never use map when you want side effects instead of return values. You can wrap a map with dorun, but in most cases it's easier to use doseq.

Also defn has an implicit do, so `(fn [x] (do (println x) (inc x)))` is the same as `(fn [x] (println x) (inc x))`.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for the tip about the implicit do, I had no idea. Hundreds of do expressions are now scheduled for execution.

Comment: Similarly, `let` accepts multiple forms so you don't need a `do` inside `let` either.

Comment: As does `when`, which I didn't make as much use of as I could have.